# ignore positive(>=0) values while calculating z score

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a column `units_sold` for which I wish to calculate z-score using groupby on each `Product_ID` but I only wish to calculate mean and standard deviation for values that are negative.

I am using `zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()`
and

`df['zscore'] = df['units_sold'].groupby(df['Product_ID']).transform(zscore)`

but this will calculate z score considering all values.

How do I restrict this to only negative values?

Comment: Can you add an example so that it's easier to answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your lambda expression with a function:

```
def customZscore(x):
    x_neg = x[x<0]
    return (x_neg - x_neg.mean()) / x_neg.std()
```

Alternatively, you could filter your data frame before applying your lambda function.

**UPDATE**
Here's a version that retains the length:

```
def customZscore(x):
    x_neg = x[x<0]
    if len(x_neg) == 0:
        zscore = [0]*len(x)
    else:
        mean_neg, std_neg = x_neg.mean(), x_neg.std()
        zscore = [v - mean_neg / std_neg if v < 0 else 0 for v in x]
    return np.array(zscore)
```

Comment: `df['zscore'] = df['units_sold'].groupby(df['Product_ID']).transform(zscore)`
When I do this, there is an error `Length of passed values is 47, index implies 374.`

Comment: Okay, so you want to return not only the zscore for values < 0 but also a placeholder for values >= 0? And you don't want to consider values >= 0 in the zscore, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Than have a look at my updated solution. Here, I am using 0 as a placeholder z score for values >= 0. Please accept my answer if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Are there any remaining questions @AmanArora ? If not, I would appreciate it if you could accept my answer.